# Bluetooth Volume Suddenly Low in Windows

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I have a PowerSpec 1710 laptop with windows 10, and a pair of Sony MDR-1000X headphones. I've been using the headphones over bluetooth with this machine for months. Normally, some volume between 20 and 40 is sufficient for listening.

Suddenly over the last few days even at 100% the output volume is extremely quiet. Meanwhile, the headset (communications) functionality volume is still as loud as ever. I have confirmed that the headphones work fine when paired to other devices.

I have tried
1. Rolling back audio drivers
2. Rolling back bluetooth drivers
3. Disabling audio enhancements
4. Manually installing audio and bluetooth drivers (note, I'm not even sure if this was successful, because windows automatically installs drivers on boot)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I did allow windows to automatically search for and install audio and bluetooth drivers before this problem began, but rolling back did not seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the headphone has an "internal" volume control that was modified to make it soft?  (appears this was the case).  For my personal headphone it's a little slider that can accidentally get knocked low.

Comment: For others with similar problems, while the Sony MDR-1000x do not have a physical knob or slider, using the touch feature to adjust the volume solved the problem.